# What differences in c/c++ language in arm and x86 architectures

Tags: c++, c, x86, arm

I'm trying to port code originally written for x86 architecture to arm.

https://github.com/SDLash3D

Originally it was developed for msvc/win32 and has many bugs in code, so there may be UB.

Code is working on x86 when compiled with gcc, but on arm it has different behaviour. It seems to lose some data in arrays and weapon switch does not work.
It affected both server and client libraries.

Application is single-threaded, so it is not synchronization problem.

Char is unsigned by default on arm, so i add `-fsigned-char` to compiler flags, but it didn't solved the problem. What other differences is there between arm and x86 c code?

I tried to compile code on arm with gcc and clang and there is no differences, so it is not a compiler bug.

P.S
I compiled code for x86 with gcc-4.9 (instead of 4.8) and got same behaviour.
After that i combined two compilers and found that problem was in net_encode.c.

By the time, sebastien chevalier found that

`iValue /= pField->multiplier;
 iValue *= pField->multiplier;`

when iValue is integer and pField->multiplier==1.0f sometimes changes integer values.

It can be fixed by adding check if pField->multiplier != 1.0f before multiply.

Comment: _"it become crazy in some plases"_ That's not a particularly helpful problem description. You're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Char is unsigned by default in C and C++. All other integer types are signed if not specified explicitly as unsigned.

Comment: Don't depend on the signedness of char. If you see people getting pedantic about what you can and cannot assume here on Stack Oveflow, then it's because they're trying to protect you from plases becoming crazy.

Comment: https://github.com/SDLash3D/
On x86 it works perfectly, on arm weapon switch does not work correctly in both server (hlsdk) and client (xashxt) code. I cannot find "bad" part of code because i don't know what can be wrong.

Comment: You REALLY need to break the problem down into something manageable. What exact part of the code breaks, in what way? This WILL need some effort on your side, by tracing/logging and/or running the code in a debugger, and tracking down the actual problem. If it's to do with network packets, I'd guess it's using unaligned memory, but could be lots of other things.

Comment: I think the arm lacks the instruction for weapon switch.

Comment: There are differences in the way C++ works on different CPUs and different compilers (see implementation defined, and undefined behaviour). However the difference between Microsoft's C++ and any of the C++ standards, is greater than the difference between C++ on one cpu, and C++ on another cpu.

Answer (score 11):

Almost impossible to say without seeing your code, but will try to answer generally.

One huge difference between x86 and ARM is the way that most x86 instructions are internally atomic, where ARM has no such thing - you have to explicitly say "execute this set of instructions exclusively". So if you have data that is updated by multiple threads, this may hit you.

There are also differences in how individual instructions behave. Without knowing what your code does, this is fairly hard to say if it affects your code or not, but one thing that can hit is "unaligned access", which is perfectly valid (albeit not optimal) in x86, but invalid (in most models) on ARM processors. So pointers must be aligned to the size of the item it accesses.

And of course, it is different code generation in the compilers, which may take different decisions based on the input code, and thus end up with code that behaves differently in all manner of ways. One that has hit me more than once is "execution order of argument function calls":

```
func(func1(), func2());
```

note that `func1()` *or* `func2()` may execute first. If you are relying on such ordering, you need to do:

```
t1 = func1();
t2 = func2();
func(t1, t2);
```

Hints:

If you don't already, enable as much warnings as you can (`-Wall` at the very least). And fix any warnings

Check for `#pragma pack` or similar "pack data structures", and similarly casts from `char *` to `int *` etc, as these can lead to unaligned access problems.

Edit: And of course, different compilers will have different bugs that may or may not make a difference in a particular compiler, processor and code combination. Although rather unlikely of clang also gives the SAME problem.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really an expert on this but there are some general things I can point out.

First, depending on the version of ARM and settings, the size, signedness and endianness of some primitive types could be different from those of x86 (especially x86_64). In this regard, well-written, portable code should never make assumptions about any of these aspects. If you need specific size and signedness, you use types from `<cstdint>` / `<stdint.h>` header. And endianness is something you should take care of too.

Second, as mentioned by Mats, one of the most notorious and behavior-changing difference between ARM and x86 is the strictness of the memory model. In short, x86 tends to be very conservative (and thus, inherently "safe" or at least, unsurprising), while ARM is a lot weaker (and thus, potentially faster). This is especially critical with concurrent code. By default, a lot of basic operations on x86 are atomic and there are many implicit full memory fences that guarantee a general consistency. Those guarding mechanisms are not present as much by default on ARM, which can lead to lots of weird behaviour.

For example, lots of naive multi-threaded code will wrongly use `volatile` variables as a way to share information or signals between threads. In many cases, this will work OK on x86 due to its conservative memory model. But on an ARM architecture, that code is likely broken.

And finally, in general, different architectures will behave slightly differently on some operations. All of these differences typically fall under the "undefined behaviour" or "implementation defined" categories of the standard. These are the most difficult bugs to find because undefined behaviour typically means that on one architecture (and compiler) one thing will happen, which might be OK, but on another architecture, something else will happen, which might **not** be OK.

There are some tools that can help you with all these issues. The main tools are so-called "sanitizers". These tools instrument your run-time code will tons of checks for all sorts of issues related to all this (i.e., you can run them with your working x86 code, and they point you towards the "dangerous" things that could behave differently on ARM or elsewhere). You can try [UBSan](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/) (undefined behaviour sanitizer, for UB operations), [TSan](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/wiki/CppManual) (thread sanitizer, for data races and dangerous cross-thread memory accesses) and [ASan](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (address sanitizer, for memory debugging in general), which are all available under both Clang and GCC. I don't know if these tools have anything special that can help for ARM, or if they even target ARM, but at the very least, fixing any issue that they point to on x86 should help tremendously when porting it to ARM.